# match opening parenthesis to the corresponding closing parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I am using java for my program
suppose i have a string such as this

```
xx(yyzz(iijj))qq((kkll)(gghh))
```

Is there any way in which i could match `xx(yyzz(iijj))` and `qq((kkll)(gghh))` separately using a regex?

Comment: I've seen it referred to BF in mixed company... but good luck with that. BF looks like a chore.

Comment: It's not so bad. I got the expression generator working quite well (if you only use constants :D), as well as expressions, a random number generator, and a tool to convert strings into compact bf code. This problem has arisen when trying to add functionality to be able to call functions from within an expression or when accessing a value in an array from within an expression

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression to find the matching parentheses instead of using another method?

Comment: Just to see if it could be done. Which it totally can in some flavors of regex such as .net's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* match nested parenthesis using regex up to a fixed level. But more than 2 level will become rather messy (2 already is, to be frank). This will match your examples:

```
\(([^()]*+|\([^()]*+\))*\)
```

A quick explanation:

```
\(              # match a '(' 
(               # open group 1
  [^()]*+       #   match any chars other than '(' and ')'
  |             #   OR
  \([^()]*+\)   #   match '(...)'
)*              # close group 1 and repeat it zero or more times
\)              # match a '('
```

See the demo on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/fN5NV)

There are regex flavors that can match an arbitrary number of nesting (Perl, .NET, PHP), but Java is not one of them.

But looking at the comment you posted under your question, I'd not handle this with regex, but a proper parser (be it a handcrafted one, or a generated).

Comment: It's my first attempt at something like this, i need to do a bit more research :)

Comment: thanks for the example, but i'll be taking your latter advice and revising the parser :)

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is no, there's not a way to do it using just a regular expression. Just iterate through the string and push the open parentheses onto a stack. Pop when you hit closed parentheses. If you try to pop or you finish and the stack isn't empty then it's invalid.

You could also do this recursively by removing the first index of '(' and lastIndex of ')' verifying that the index of '(' is less than the index of ')'

Comment: ok thanks. I like a straight answer. May need to rethink my current code then. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: And it's done. Implemented something such as you described, except i kept a counter instead of a stack. increment the counter for each ( found and decrement it for each ). if the counter reaches 0 it means i've hit a match as i described it in the question. Thanks :) I would vote your answer up, but i don't have enough rep yet :S

Comment: @CedricMamo you should be able to mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark below the upvote/downvote. Thanks.

Comment: @CedricMamo Can you post the code you implemented as an answer, then?