# Remove everything between the first opening parenthesis & and it's respective closing parenthesis (parenthesis included). Is this possible?

Tags: python, sed, scripting, grep

I have a file with a lot of lines of text like so: 
(text)

There are many instances where this occurs: 
In textfile1.txt: 
logging.info(text text text(text text) text text)

Which if I use: 
`$ sed -i '/(/,/)/d' textfile` 
Returns
' text text)'

There are also many instances like so: 
(text 
text text(text text) 
text text)

I want to remove everything between the first opening parenthesis & and it's respective closing parenthesis (including both parenthesis). Doesn't matter what method is used, looking for any. Is this possible?

I tried writing my own python script but I didn't even remotely get close. It would be easier to look for a different solution than to fix my broken program I believe.

I've seen some other posts like: 
[Find text between Opening parenthesis closing [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272382/find-text-between-opening-parenthesis-closing) 
[match opening parenthesis to the corresponding closing parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118066/match-opening-parenthesis-to-the-corresponding-closing-parenthesis) 
[regex: parse opening closing parenthesis with other parenthesis in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898762/regex-parse-opening-closing-parenthesis-with-other-parenthesis-in-between)
But I am really bad with regex and they all use regex and I don't know

Answer (score 1):

You can make GNU `sed` loop until all pairs are removed:

```
sed -z ':a;s/([^()]*)//;ta' textfile1.txt
```

EDIT: I added `-z`, as suggested by Ed.

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk, e.g. given this input:

```
$ cat file
(text)
logging.info(text text text(text text) text text)
foo (text
text text(text text)
text text) bar
```

then using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{ while( gsub(/\([^()]*)/,"") ); } 1' file

logging.info
foo  bar
```

otherwise using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
END {
    while ( gsub(/\([^()]*)/,"",rec) );
    printf "%s", rec
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file

logging.info
foo  bar
```

Comment: Hello this is a good solution but I've identified a flaw. In my tests, it breaks if a "parenthesis that does not have a matching parenthesis" is inside a set of matching parenthesis; such as the following: In textfile.txt: ```text("text ( text text")``` or ```text(text text The character for a right parenthesis looks like ")". text text text)```

Comment: The edit your question to provide sample input that includes that case. All we have to go on when writing a script is what you tell us that script has to be able to handle.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed ':a
s/([^()]*)//g;t a
/(/!b
$b
N;b a' file
```

Remove balanced `(`...`)` until none are left. If a `(` is still present and the last line of input hasn't been read: add the next line to the pattern space, and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
def a(test_str):
  ret = ''
  skip1c = 0
  skip2c = 0
  for i in test_str:
      if i == '[':
          skip1c += 1
      elif i == '(':
          skip2c += 1
      elif i == ']' and skip1c > 0:
          skip1c -= 1
      elif i == ')'and skip2c > 0:
          skip2c -= 1
      elif skip1c == 0 and skip2c == 0:
          ret += i
  return ret

x = "ewq[a [(b] ([c))]] This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]"
x = a(x)
print x
print repr(x)
```

Comment: It would help to add the final result to your answer and choose variable names that are more descriptive. Also, unless you specify this is for Python 2, use `print()` with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function such as `find_parens()` posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29992065/15187728) to find indices of matching parentheses in the string. This function will also raise an exception if the string has unbalanced parentheses.

For a string

```
s = "This is a (little (really small)) test (?)."
```

calling `find_parens(s)` gives:

```
{18: 31, 10: 32, 39: 41}
```

The indices are organized into a dictionary. We can replace it by a list of tuples sorted by the first elements of the tuples:

```
sorted(list(find_parens(s).items()), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

This gives:

```
[(10, 32), (18, 31), (39, 41)]
```

The first tuple gives the index of the first opening parenthesis in the string and its matching closing parenthesis:

```
bounds = sorted(list(find_parens(s).items()), key= lambda x: x[0])[0]
print(bounds)
```

This gives:

```
(10, 32)
```

It remains to remove the part of the string defined by these indices:

```
out = s[:bounds[0]] + s[bounds[1]+1:]
print(out)
```

We get:

```
'This is a  test (?).'
```